# Fix/Freeze/Clamp Object Info at certain value

Tags: objects, node-editor, color, mathematics

I am using an object's 3D position to apply a diffuse colour. I have a selection of objects that are different Z positions and hence have the colour ramp applied to them. As objects merge back into their final places I would like them to retain their colours.

The position of the plates when exploded will not be as they are now so I cannot just simply reduce the scale of the ramp when they contract back in. I need them to "remember" the value of their Z displacement for the colour ramp to use that data.

Basically I need a node (or some way to do it with what I have) that can be key framed to "freeze" it's output value.

H

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Colour when spread apart]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "baking" for this. Colors can be written on image texture.

1) First, setup UV for all objects. Select all objects, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for "Smart UV Project".

2) Next, connect what you want to bake to emission shader. Add an image texture and put it on node setup like this:

[image]

3) Find "Bake" section in render settings, select type to "emit" and press "Bake"

[image]

4) If you will do everything right you will get an image like this, save it.

[image]

5) Finally, connect image node to your node setup